# How to make chat application, one-to-one chat UI

Tags: javascript, socket.io, chat

Actually I doing a chat application for my college. I am using node.js socket.io and express.js. I have done the public chat. That is, all user can chat publicly,its working fine.. but my problem is how to make private chat, ie; one-to-one chat.

I worked hard but i don't know the proper way where to start. 
1. i tried to send with socketID. Its work fine..but that is not a good way, i think so.
2. how to pop-up an UI DIV on remote user when I pinged him.

plz help me.
Any link, any tutorial, any framework, plz share....
 Thanks advance,

Answer (score 0):

Without socket.io you can look at this : [Server with net under nodejs](https://gist.github.com/creationix/707146)

It makes a TCP server that you can use. Then you can create a client with nodeJS if you want or just use a TCP connexion

Example of client code :

```
var util = require("util");
var net = require("net");

var client = net.connect({port: 1337}, function () {
    util.log("Client connected");
});


client.on("data", function (d) {
    d = "" + d; //d is a buffer
    util.log(d);
});

setInterval(function() { client.write("Hello"); }, 1000);
```

Comment: hello @Waxo Thanks for your reply...
But how to pop up a UI on the remote system when I ping him.
For eg, in Facebook if I click on my friends name and enter a msg a  new chat pop-up get enabled and the two users starts their chat. like that how to create a UI for that....
plz help me... Thanks for your reply....

Comment: But how to pop up a UI on the remote system when I ping him. For eg, in Facebook if I click on my friends name and enter a msg a new chat pop-up get enabled and the two users starts their chat. 

is there any css or jquery trick to open a pop up on remote system(end user)

Comment: Check webkit. I think it's the best way to do it.